# Understanding REST in terms of scalability, performance,

Tags: performance, rest, scalability

I just want to know if my thoughts concerning REST are right. Let's imagine we have a shopping site. With a conventional approach the shopping cart would be stored in the users session so that the server has to manage many items for user( User#1: item1, item2, item3; User#2: itemA,itemB, item3,...). So the server has to have lots of memory/computing power if there are more than a thousand users browsing on the site and adding items to their shopping cart.

In a REST approach there is no session, so the client has all information about the items in the shopping cart. This means that the server doesn't need to have such big memory requirements and I can easily scale this.

Now if I add an item in the non-REST-approach to the shopping cart it would go directly into the session. On the other hand, if I add an item in the REST-approach, I have to update the entity in the database (/shoppingcart/1234/) and this would take a bit longer since I have to go one level deeper (client->server->database).

Is this correct so far or am I missing or misunderstanding a point?

Comment: REST doesn't care whether the shopping cart is on the client-side or the server-side. REST is, in your case, about how resources on the web, and operations on them, are exposed to clients.

Comment: ok, i've understood this point with GET,POST,PUT,DELETE. But if i decide to manage my shopping cart not on the client than it would be slower with REST since i can only store them in the database and not in a session of the server?

Comment: that doesn't have anything to do with REST. You're conflating REST with a few other concepts (cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677893/understanding-rest-in-terms-of-scalability-performance/6678003#6678003)).

Comment: @bzlm, the link is not pointing to either of the answers.

Comment: @bzlm your first comment is nice explanation about REST but question is still same that how scalability works with REST. ?

Comment: It used to :) @Reddy and too late to edit the comment now. Mohammad, question is rather how using Web APIs instead of "direct APIs" affects performance. Scalability is increased by using disconnected services, but latency in operations may suffer. So it's not a question about REST at all, but about having to go "over the web" instead of "directly to the database".

Answer (score 4):

> In a REST approach there is no session, so the client has all information about the items in the shopping cart.

The REST statelessness constraint doesn't imply that the client needs to keep track of all information about the items in the shopping cart (please don't do that). But it does mean that the state of the shopping cart is addressable (that the client has all the information needed to service the request).

Consider the following URL:

/shopping-cart/john.howes

My understanding of the statelessness constraint is that if I or you or anyone navigates to that link, we will get some representation of the same resource (assuming we have the authorization to view it). It may be XML or JSON or HTML, and it may be in English or French, but the underlying resource is the same. And if I bookmark that URL and view it later on another device or email it to a friend, we would get the same resource (assuming it still exists and we have authorization to view it).

So, because I had a link to /shopping-cart/john.howes, I had all the information needed to service the request.

> Now if I add an item in the non-REST-approach to the shopping cart it would it would go directly in the session. If I add an item in the REST-approach I have to update the entity in the database (/shoppingcart/1234/) and this would take a bit longer since I have to go one level deeper (client->server->database).

I think, whether you're using REST or not, adding large objects to session state is a recipe for disaster (for maintainability, scalability, and sanity). So, I'd bite the bullet and use a database. And I think you're essentially right: REST doesn't say much about how data is stored on the server, but it does imply that you don't store the current state of a user's session in memory on your web server. I think you have lots of options for optimizing for performance. Keeping everything in session is not a very good option.

I hope this helps.

John

Comment: Have you heard about RESTFest? http://www.restfest.org  It would be great to have you join us.

Comment: Don't want to continue the chat, @bzlm, so I responded via twitter. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct ways of doing a shopping cart in REST.  One is where you actually make the shopping cart a resource and assign it a URI, as you describe.  The other is where the contents of the shopping cart are kept on the client right up until the point where the user places the order.

There are pros and cons to both approaches and yes, storing the shopping cart as a resource will  require storing the shopping cart in a database (it could be a in memory database though!).

However, I don't think trying to do a perf comparison on this aspect, between using sessions and storing carts as resources, is particularly valuable.

Comment: But the question is still same that how scalability works

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Maintaining the shopping cart in the client state means the server doesn't have to maintain cart state and therefore can scale to an infinite number of consumers with pending carts.

Comment: That is fine, we can save cart in cookies but there is no need REST for this.